# Error Deploying Web application into my local IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7, web-deployment

I am making a publish of my application to my local **IIS** and I am getting in my browser an error:

**Service Unavailable**

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I went to my **IIS** and noticed that the '**DefaultAppPool**' stopped, restarted again and try to access to the app again and same error and the app pool stopped again.

then I went to the **Event Viewer** and I was getting this error:

The worker process for application pool 'DefaultAppPool' encountered an error 
'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions' trying to read configuration data from file 
'\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\machine.config', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.

any help??

Comment: Any update?  I'm hitting the same problem.

Comment: what I did to solve my issue, at least, temporally, was give permission to the `machine.config` file to **IIS_IUSRS** group (read&write), i checked my coworkers machines permissions to that file and they have that permission by default, maybe some process change that permission to that file in my machine

Comment: i tried this [MSDN Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2011/06/21/iis-service-startup-problem-error-6801-transaction-support-within-the-specified-resource-manager-is-not-started-or-was-shut-down-due-to-an-error.aspx). Worked with errors. But errors gone when created new iis site.